# What is the browser support for CSS3 Box-sizing?

Tags: css, browser-support

I know the newer browser versions support box-sizing, but does IE down to 7 support it? What about the other main browsers? FF? Safari?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Box-sizing is supported in IE8+. See: http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing